ImportError: cannot import name ‘process_tweet’ from ‘utils’
I’m presently taking Natural Language Processing specialization via Coursera.
I couldn’t progress with the week 1 assignment because of the error encounter. The error is "ImportError: cannot import name ‘process_tweet’ from ‘utils’ ".
Error message screenshot is attached. I have searched online resources including Google search and YouTube without solution.
ImportError: cannot import name 'process_tweet' from 'utils' 
(C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\utils\__init__.py)

I have searched online resources including Google search and YouTube without solution.
